# How to model a Sale/Discount price for a Specific Category of a Product or a Specific Product?

Tags: database-design

[image: Database]

This is my database Model for the Products, Category, and Sales(or Discount)

I am building an Ecommerce Website. and I sell different products like Cellphone, Television, Clothes, Shoes, etc. almost just like Amazon.

Am I modelling right about the sales table? I wanted to make everything dynamic. I have four questions.

**First question:**
First I wanted to make a Sale for a Specific product (I wanna select it like a checkbox in the front end) one or more products and with a specific date time period like October 1 to September 1 (I'll be the one who set's how much percentage is off for the sale). For example: I have a 2020 version of a new released phone, television, shoes, clothes, and hat. and the first product or any random product that is 2020 but only in each category. How can I do it?

**Second question:** How do I make a sale for a Specific Category with all the products listed in that category for a date range for example October 1 to
September 1? (I will be again the one who set's the percentage of how much is discounted?)

**Third question**: How do i make a sale for all of the products/category? like a year end sale that is atleast 2 weeks before 2020 end

**Fourth question:**
How can I model all of my questions? and does any of my questions made the right database design? based on the picture

Btw I am using the mongo db, Node.js, Express, and React in short MERN Stack.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question per post. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please for code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lexical :

- TABLE(#column) <-- column is a foreign key of TABLE
- TABLE(**column**) <-- column is a primary key

There is a lot of question, and kinda a lot of stuff to review, so i'll take them step by step :

**1. The given model look wrong in many way :**

1. Every entity must be named singular as : PRODUCT (and not PRODUCTS), SALE (and not SALES).This is because you are representing ONE entity for each table line.
2. **SALE**(**id**, #CATEGORY, #PRODUCT) If you can have a sales for a whole category of product, or for a single product. Then you should have the following table : ***SALE_CATEGORY***(**#id_sale**, **#CATEGORY**);***SALE_PRODUCT***(**#id_sale, #PRODUCT**);***SALE***(**id**, amount, start_date, end_date). In fact SALE(**id**, #CATEGORY, #PRODUCT) is not wrong thanks to the [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) (id). But if you do so, you'll have one of the two columns (#CATEGORY or #PRODUCT) which would be null for every entity. Even though you are using NoSql, this will me a mess to maintain.
3. If a product rely to one inventory at a time, then the way you did it by having a foreign key on **PRODUCT** entity is correct. But have you think about the fact that the same product could be stored yo multiple inventory ? Like you got some quantity of a product on one inventory, and some quantity to another ? If this could happen, then you should have a **PRODUCT_INVENTORY**(**#id_product**, **#id_inventory**, qte).
4. I think this one is just a mistake, but you have two `price` attribute in the **PRODUCT** table

**2. Your first question**

1. I think I have been answering this question previously in 1.2.

**3. Your second question**

1. Same, an answer have already being given in 1.2.

**4. Your third question**

1. I think you've already guess that's always the same thing, since you can create a new entry for each sale, then you decide the starting date and the ending date...

**5. Your fourth question**

1. I suggest you to apply the change that I suggest, and then make an edit of your post to review the new model.

**EDIT**

The foreign key `inventory` on *Product* table is no longer needed, because this relation is already represented by the `product` foreign key inside of `Inventory` table.
But your entity `Inventory` is not verry clear to me.
What is an inventory ? Is it kind of a specific location in a warehouse ? It'll make sens in e-commerce, you usualy store product in a wharehouse, then, when a customer order a product, you retire the ordered product quantity from this place.

Showing you what I got in mind on a standard diagram ERD ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–relationship_model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)) :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I highly appreciate it. I already made changes to the table. Did I do it the correct way? in the Sale_Category and Sale_Product table I used the sale foreign key to the Sale Table is that corrent? I am thinking to put another entity to the Sale_Category and Sale_Product the salePrice but still have both foreign key for the sale?

Comment: On your updated model, you don't need to have the surrogate key ``id`` into *SALE_CATEGORY* or into *SALE_PRODUCT*. Thre primary key is a compound key (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) composed by the two foreign key (#SALE, #PRODUCT) or (#SALE,  #CATEGORY). Think about it, if you have One ``sale_id`` and one ``product_id`` did you have a unique SALE_PRODUCT entity ?.. Yes ! So the primary key is composed by the two fields.

Comment: ``I am thinking to put another entity to the Sale_Category and Sale_Product the salePrice but still have both foreign key for the sale?`` No. If I got it the right way, a sales is just a discount on some products ? So basically, it is just a percentage of the price which is being discount am I right ? This amount (percentage) of discount is represent by the ``amount`` property.

Comment: Yes. Yes it's just a percentage sale for a specific products or a specific category which always turns back to original once a certain period ends. so in short this database model is good for sale in a specific product and specific category?.

Comment: If you want to make a 25% sale for the period 20/04/2020 to 25/05/2020 : ``INSERT INTO SALE(25, 20/04/2020, 25/04/2020)``  <-- LET'S SAY IT'S THE FIRST SALE SO ID IS AUTO INCREMENT TO 1.
Now you want this sale to apply on a category like FOOTBAL and TV : ``INSERT INTO SALE_CATEGORY('FOOTBAL', 1)``, ``INSERT INTO SALE_CATEGORY('TV', 1)``. Now if you want to have a sale for a specific product : ``INSERT INTO SALE_PRODUCT(*product_id*, *sale_id*)``

Comment: I can't suggest anything better than reading this course about how to modelise : https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/how-to-model-relational-database-with-erd.jsp
(There is a ton about ERD, choose the one you prefer). And use this cool free tools to make ERD : https://app.lucidchart.com.  ERD will make your life simpler by having a clear representation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me a lot on understanding my problem.